# I am getting Notification problem in my device

Tags: java, android

I was trying to make a simple app. But I am getting a simple problem like I am not receiving notification in my device which is Android pie.
I make a button in a fragment, and when I click it I make a method to show the notification to the user, but when I click my button I didn't receive any notification. So if anyone finds a problem in my code please answer me.
Here is my code below:-
Main Fragment:-

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    View view;
    private Button clickme;
    private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        clickme = view.findViewById(R.id.Click_me);
        notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getActivity());
        clickme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "simple toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                sendOnChannel1();
            }
        });
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    public void sendOnChannel1() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder)
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
                        .setContentTitle("Simple notification")
                        .setContentText("This is a test");


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getContext().getSystemService(getContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

activity fragment.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="search"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorRed"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Click_me"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for reading my question please reply me if anyone finds a problem.

Comment: Can you please send me the new code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this its working properly**

```
 //send notification
private void sendNotification() {
            AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            assert audio != null;
            switch (audio.getRingerMode()) {
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                    break;
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                    break;
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                    break;
            }

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setGroupSummary(true);

            // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("chanelid", "Notification", importance);
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                assert notificationManager != null;
                notificationBuilder.setChannelId("chanelid");

                if (notificationManager != null) {
                    List<NotificationChannel> channelList = notificationManager.getNotificationChannels();
                    for (int i = 0; channelList != null && i < channelList.size(); i++) {
                        notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(channelList.get(i).getId());
                    }
                }

                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
            notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
```

Comment: bro thanks for sending but this method is also not working

Comment: in which device you are testing ? and check weather notification is on or not for that app@HunnyArora

Comment: Yes thanks you I tried some new methods and finally solved my problem

Comment: what you've changed ? @HunnyArora

Comment: Like I Stopped All Of my applications which control notifications of my apps in my phones I unblock my phone notifications

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public void sendOnChannel1() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder)
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
                    .setWhen(0)
                    .setTicker("Simple notification")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
                    .setContentTitle("Simple notification")
                    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(),0,
                       new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class) ,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT))
                    .setContentText("This is a test");


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getContext().getSystemService(getContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                /* Create or update. */
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                        "appname",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
            notificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            CommonUtilities._Log(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
}
```

Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID could be any integer number.

Comment: It is still not working and this is not showing me notifications;

Comment: @HunnyArora on which device you're testing?

Comment: @HunnyArora I've modified my answer and included `setContentIntent` which will be triggered when you click on the notification

Answer (score 1):

**above android 7 versions supports notification channel Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.**

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
            .setContentTitle("Simple notification")
            .setContentText("This is a test");


    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {


        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("xyz", "xyz", importance);
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.WHITE);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        mBuilder.setChannelId("");

        if (notificationManager != null) {
            //do what you want
        }

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: It is still not working and not showing me notifications

Comment: try my another answer its working on my android pie device @HunnyArora